# VB6 keyword Set what does it mean?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I been browsing an old VB6 code and I saw something like this

```
 Set AST = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
```

I have experience using VB6 and VB.NET but I never use this keyword `Set` before in my VB6 projects. I researched a lot in the internet what is the use of `Set` and what I only know is the usage in `Properties` which is only I know in VB.NET

```
Public Property myProperty As String
    Get
      Return _myProperty
    End Get
    Set(value as String)
      _myProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and I think `Set` is used differently on the code above. What is the difference of the two approaches? I want to know what does the `Set` do in VB6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Set` is assigning a new reference to the `AST` variable, rather than assigning a value to (the object currently referenced by `AST`)'s default property.

---

<strike>There's not much VB 6 documentation around on the web, but</strike><sup>1</sup> some of the help for VB.Net still references the older ways.

See [Default Property Changed for Visual Basic 6 Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7bfkxc1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> In Visual Basic 6.0, default properties are supported on objects. On a Label control, for example, Caption is the default property, and the two assignments in the following example are equivalent.

```
Dim lbl As Label 
lbl = "Important" 
lbl.Caption = "Important"
```

> While default properties enable a certain amount of shorthand in writing Visual Basic code, they have several drawbacks:
>
> ...
>
> - Default properties make the Set statement necessary in the Visual Basic language. The following example shows how Set is needed to indicate that an object reference, rather than a default property, is to be assigned.

```
Dim lbl1 As Label, lbl2 As Label 
lbl1 = "Saving" ' Assign a value to lbl1's Caption property. 
lbl2 = lbl1       ' Replace lbl2's Caption property with lbl1's. 
Set lbl2 = lbl1   ' Replace lbl2 with an object reference to lbl1.
```

---

So, in VB.Net, `Let` and `Set` became obsolete (in fact, `Let` was already pretty much obsolete in VB 6) because the language rules changed. An assignment `A = B`, if `A` is a reference, is always assigning a new reference to `A`.

---

<sup>1</sup>MarkJ has supplied links to the older VB6 documentation in the comments.

Comment: Not completely irrelevant: default properties still exist in VB.NET, but only for indexed properties. For example, default properties in .NET allow you to write `myList(index)` instead of `myList.Item(index)`.

Comment: @StevenLiekens - that is covered in the page I linked to - it covers default properties for both VB 6 and .NET and highlights the differences, e.g. "In Visual Basic 2008, default properties are not supported unless they take arguments.". I wanted to keep my answer focussed on the `Set` for VB classic.

Comment: Oh.. I stopped reading the MSDN page before "...unless they take arguments". My bad.

Comment: +1 but the VB6 documentation is still available on MSDN. From the VB6 user guide, here's [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266283(v=vs.60).aspx), [Let](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243390(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Making a Property or Method the Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263533(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @MarkJ - My Google-fu let me down. I did search for quite a while but all I could find were helpful guides to migrating to VB.NET