# How can I pass a cell range as an argument?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

How can I create a function in VBA so that I can pass a cell range as an argument?

For example, I want to call the function in the spreadsheet in a random cell by writing

```
=function_name(A2:A7)
```

My code gives me a ?NAME# error when I call it in the spreadsheet.

```
Public Function xyz ( ByRef x() As Variant, sizeOfSelection As Integer )
xyz=x(0);
End Function
```

It is coded in a Module and my Macros is on.

Comment: `ByVal x As Range`. Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/57159554/11683 if you want to get universal.

Comment: What is the function supposed to be doing?

Comment: Your example code has different issues. First of all it has a syntax error, secondly you never user the parameter `sizeoOfSelection and thirdly your call has only one parameter. And a range is never an array what is your first parameter.

Comment: @Storax, yes, also `sizeOfSelection` is not passed in the given example

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Public Function xyz (rng as Range) As String
    dim arr as variant
    arr = rng.value
    if rng.cells.count>1 then
        Debug.print arr(1, 1), arr(1, ubound(arr,2))
        xyz = rng.Address & " - " & arr(1, 1)
    Else
        xyz = rng.value
    End if
End Function
```

This is only an example? What would you like it to do/return?

Answer (score 0):

In the following code we simply evaluate the argument which if a Range will call its default member which is .Value which will for a Range of more than one cell return a variant array.   Conversely, wrapping a variant array in brackets does nothing so this it is unaffected.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("FooBar")

    AllowBothRangeAndVariantArray rng
    AllowBothRangeAndVariantArray rng.Value2
End Sub

Function AllowBothRangeAndVariantArray(ByVal v As Variant)
    v = (v)  '* if v is a Range this will call the default member which is value
    'Debug.Print v(1, 1)
End Function
```

So this is a one-liner (if you omit the Debug.Print which is there for debugging)

I've also tested this from the worksheet.

Comment: Has the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477223/11683 originally had. Will fail if `Range("FooBar")` is a single cell.

Comment: @GSerg That wasn't the point I was trying to make.  The point i was trying to make is that use brackets to convert a Range to a Variant, whilst leaving a Variant unchanged.  Works for single cells as well.  Of course one then has to go on and check dimensions if your functions logic depends upon the shape..

Comment: `v(1,1)` assumes a 2D array. Value of a single cell is not an array at all.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Answer is to be adapted by the questioner.  Text does say delete the Debug.Print in parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

### Range UDF

Try something like these:

```
Option Explicit

Function xyz(CountRange As Range) As Long
    xyz = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(CountRange)
End Function

Function xyzSum(SumRange As Range) As Long
    xyzSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRange)
End Function

Function xyzIf(CountRange As Range, Criteria as long) As Long
    xyzIf = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CountRange, Criteria)
End Function
```