# Setting default property fails because it is read only?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

This code was converted from VB6 to VB.Net:

```
Public prvMainForm = VB6Form    
If prvMainForm IsNot Nothing Then
    CObj(prvMainForm).StatusBar.Panels(1) = "Initializing Folders..."
End If
```

(My code is quite long so I've just added this `if` block which is where the actual error occurs.)

The error is seen on the single line inside the If statement:

> Property 'Item' is 'ReadOnly'

Comment: Apparently you meant to set a property of the object that `.Panels(1)` returns. So specify that property.

Comment: I tried .Panels(1) in the immediate window and seems like it should be .Panels(1).Text

Comment: In VB6 that statement is equivalent to `Set CObj(...).Panels(1) = ...`.  With Set indicating that you meant to replace the object instead of assigning the panel's Text property.  VB.NET dropped support for Set, too much ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

`StatusBar.Panels(1)` returns a `MSComctlLib.Panel`.

`StatusBar.Panels(1) = "Initializing Folders..."` is valid in VB6 because of [default properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683).

Default properties in VB.NET must have parameters. A parameterless property cannot be default and therefore cannot be omitted. Thus, `.Panels(1) = "..."` is understood by VB.NET as an attempt to replace the entire `Panel` in the `Panels` property, which is not allowed.

You can look up the name of the default property in the VB6 object browser, which turns out to be `Property _ObjectDefault As String`, so you should be able to do:

```vb
CObj(prvMainForm).StatusBar.Panels(1).[_ObjectDefault] = "Initializing Folders..."
```

As you have observed, assigning `Text` should do the same:

```vb
CObj(prvMainForm).StatusBar.Panels(1).Text = "Initializing Folders..."
```