# How to set ADODB connection property in C#

Tags: c#, adodb

I'm trying to convert a sample for running a SQL/XML "UpdateGram" from VB to C#.

VB Example:

```
 conn.Properties("SQLXML Version") = "SQLXML.4.0"
```

C# Attempts:

```
 conn.Properties["SQLXML Version"] = "SQLXML.4.0";
```

Error: cannot be assigned, is read only.

VB Source: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/updategrams/executing-an-updategram-by-using-ado-sqlxml-4-0?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `conn.Properties["SQLXML Version"].Value = "SQLXML.4.0";`?.. That is literally what is shown in the code samples at your very link.

Comment: Cool, it works,  thanks.  Do you want to put in the Answer?

Comment: Did you see any C# on that link?

Comment: No, but I did see all the `cmd.Properties("Output Stream").Value = strmOut` in the VB blocks. That purple block is the only one to omit the `.Value`.

Comment: I didn't get that far yet; was working one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
conn.Properties["SQLXML Version"].Value = "SQLXML.4.0";
```

That is exactly what is shown in the codes samples at [that link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/updategrams/executing-an-updategram-by-using-ado-sqlxml-4-0?view=sql-server-ver15) you've mentioned.

I see where the confusion could have arrived from though, there is a purple "Notes" block that does (erroneously) contain the `conn.Properties("SQLXML Version") = "SQLXML.4.0"` line. This appears to be a leftover from VB6/A, where [parameterless default properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59721059/11683) were allowed. They are not allowed in VB.NET, so that line wouldn't work in VB.NET either.