# ERROR 91 - object variable or with block not set

Tags: excel, vba

Getting a runtime error for the variable `ws`. Tried almost everything i.e. changing the variable type, using `Set` to declare etc... Please help!

```vb
Sub program()
    Dim var1 As String,  wb As Workbook, SVlink As String, SAlink As String, ws As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        x = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address  ‘using the address of the button to
        'perform some operation
    
        var1 = Range(x).Offset(-17, 8).Address
        x = Range(x).Offset(-13, 8).Address
        y = Range(x).Offset(12, 0).Address
        Set ws = Range(x, y).find(what:="Nothing found")
    End With
    
    If ws <> "Nothing found" Then '---> ERROR!
        'some code here…..
    Else
        'some code here
End sub
```

Comment: To test if you found a match you'd use `If Not ws Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare different types. `ws` will returrn `Range` object if found or `Nothing` if not found. If I understand what you want right then there should be `If Not ws Is Nothing Then ...`.

Comment: The comparison of different types is not the problem here. `ws.Value` would be [implicitly used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683).

Comment: If nothing was found, then `Nothing` will be returned and it does not have `Value` property.

Comment: Thank you lovely people for the solution..variable ws returns nothing so cant be compared to a string...