# Why is IF-THEN-ELSE code not working on VBA?

Tags: vba

I would like to compare two cells and it should display "OK" or "NOT OK".

When I used an excel formula, it worked properly.

However when I tried it using VBA, I am not getting the correct results.

Below is a simpler example of my data:

| Fee1 | Fee2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.009 | 0.009 |

To note that in my worksheet, Fee1 is generated via a VBA vlookup function and Fee2 is generated via a case statement VBA code.

My code is as per below:

```
If Range("L2") <> Range("M2") Then
    Range("N2").Value = "NOT OK"
Else
    Range("N2").Value = "OK"
End If

Debug.Print Range("N2")
Debug.Print Range("L2")
Debug.Print Range("m2")
```

I used debug print to check and got the results below:

```
NOT OK
0.009 
0.009
```

I am perplexed at what i am doing wrong.

Comment: and `Fee1` is which column? `M`? `N`? `L`?

Comment: Try to print the difference between Range("L2").Value and Range("M2").Value, and find the conclusion that those values are not equal.

Comment: the statement  If Range("L2") <> Range("M2") Then  compere ranges , and L2 is not M2 range, you should compere values like If Range("L2").value <> Range("M2").value Then

Comment: "IF-THEN-ELSE-END IF" always works in VBA. You only must understand what the code compares against **what you think it compares**... If the two values are differently calculated, the maybe are different on a 19th decimal. Try rounding the values at the same number of decimals.

Comment: @braX Fee1 is L and Fee2 is M then I wanted to display "NOT OK" or "OK" in N

Comment: @xShen The statement `If Range("L2") <> Range("M2")` [compares values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683), not ranges.

Comment: @Luuk Yes I am getting a difference of 1.73472347597681E-18  when I debug print the difference. What i found weird is that when I used the excel formula, it is working properly

Comment: @Nini Because you are using [precision as displayed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result#method-2-precision-as-displayed)?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks a lot! I added it to my code and it works!!

Comment: @Nini You should have consulted https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915462/11683 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compare the values with a limited number of decimals like:

```
If Round(Range("L2").Value, 3) <> Round(Range("M2").Value, 3) Then
```