# What is the Purpose of the "Varg" Argument when Referring to a Userform Object?

Tags: vba, initialization, userform

I have always been under the understanding that in VBA we are unable to pass variables to a userform upon its creation/initialization. However, I had placed an opening parenthesis after the object name and a tooltip came up suggesting that this may not necessarily be true *(or more likely I am simply just misinterpreting it)*:

[image]

So out of curiosity I attempted to see if I could pass a variable to the userform using `varg`:

[image]

but to no surprise [it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gz8x.png).

---

So ultimately the question is what is the purpose of `varg`? To me it actually looks like it would be used for indexing multiple separate instances of the userform since it actually appears to be an argument for the property `.Item()` and not for the actual object itself, but the only way I've ever known to create multiple userform objects is by setting them to a variable, such as:

```
Dim uf1 As MyUserForm, uf2 as MyUserform
Set uf1 = New MyUserform
set uf2 = New Myuserform
```

Can userforms actually be serialized and indexed a different way that would make use of this `varg` variable?

---

> *Note: This is not a question about how to pass external variables to a Userform - I am aware of numerous ways to accomplish this **after its initialization** (by passing via a Public Property, Function, or Variable within the object's code module or even less preferably an external global/public variable in a standard module).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UserForm` has a [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683) `Controls`. It returns an instance of `Controls` class.

The `Controls` class, in turn, has a default property `Item(varg) As Object`.

So `With New udfVendorDrillDown(varg)` is the same as `With New udfVendorDrillDown.Controls.Item(varg)`, which is probably not what you hoped it was.

You still cannot pass arguments to UserForms constructors. Or any class constructors in fact.