# Excel VBA - Worksheet.Range returns value, not Range object

Tags: excel, vba

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Range) the `Worksheet.Range` function should return the Range object. However, in my case, this function returns the Value of the specified cell.

Is there some configuration I'm missing? I'm using Excel 2016.

My super simple code:

```
Public Function fn(param) As Variant
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "hi"
    fn = 1
End Function
```

Error message after running function: #VALUE! Error in Value

When I inputted the range of cells ("A1:D1") the function returned an array of cell values. I also tried assigning the range to a temporary variable and specifying its type as `Range` did not help:

```
Dim temp As Range
temp = Worksheets(1).Range("A1") 'Would break here
```

I also tried with `ActiveWorksheet.Range`  and `Sheets("name")` and the results were the same.

Comment: Are you calling that `fn(param)` from a sheet cell?

Comment: yes, I was hoping to use it in the function in the future

Comment: You have two unrelated effects: changing sheets from a sheet and inadvertently using the [default property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18051644/11683) of the Range object which is `Value`. Please refer to the links at the top.